# I tried to change the color with JS But it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting an error while running this code in Firefox console.
Error : TypeError: redSquare is null
However in codepen it works fine.

I don't know why it is happening. Nothing is happening in the browser.

```js
 /* Document Object Model */


const redSquare = document.querySelector('.red-square');
redSquare.style.color = 'limegreen';

 const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.js-target');
 for (let i = 0 ; i < elementsToChange.length; i++){
     const currentElement = elementsToChange[i];
     currentElement.innerText = "Modified by Js!";
 }
```

```css
.red-square {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: black;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Part-6</title>
    <link href="../CSS3/1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src= "../JavaScript/6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class = "red-square">DOM</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="js-target">Unchanged</li>
        <li class="js-target">Unchanged</li>
        <li>Won't Change</li>
        <li class="js-target">Unchanged</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap your JS with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {/*...*/});` (you need to wait for the elements to exist)

Comment: Waiting for loading window?

Comment: You can add the <script> tag after the <body> tag,

Comment: You should at least put your code to the bottom of body

Comment: @Leonid it worked as you said brother.
But what is the reason behind it ?
As far as I know script of js can be put anywhere right ? Correct me if I'm wrong chuck

Comment: @Leonid I have put the script at the end of the body tag and it worked, But Why Now ?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('missingSelector')` returns `null`

`document.querySelectorAll('missingSelector')` returns `NodeList` (.length = 0)

So be sure the DOM content is loaded and ready to be found.
Wrap your code with `window.onload = function(){...your code here}` or other ways.

And it's better if you put your script to the bottom of `<body>` straight before `</body>`.

The reason is parsing and interpreter machine that takes the values of variables on the first cycle. So the variables take values `undefined` or `null` firstly. Also DOM Structure needs some time to be built, in that time js is already working.

Better practise to put script to the bottom, but it doesn't give 100% guarantee. The best practise to wrap your depending on DOM code to `window.onload` or `"DOMContentLoaded"` eventListener of document.

That's why it is better to initialize and define all your functions and constants in separate file or outside of the main function (ex. window.onload). Inside the only depending on DOM elements functions and events.

Comment: So it's a better practice to put script at the end of the body ?

Comment: @Thelostcause exactly, but using the window.onload and others is MUST DO component of js usage in browsers.